# Occasional PDO Connection Exception in error_log

Tags: mysql, pdo, database-connection

I am connecting to my MySql database using PDO as follows -

```
$dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname='mydb', "username", "pswd");
$dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This works fine most of the time. However when I check the error_log, I occasional see the following traces of connection error.

```
[27-Jul-2015 08:14:15 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] 
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)' in
 /home6/uname/public_html/config_db.php:3

Stack trace:
#0 /home6/uname/public_html/config_db.php(3): 
      PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'username', 'pswd')
#1 /home6/uname/public_html/dir/index.php(150): include_once('/home6/uname...')
#2 {main}
      thrown in /home6/uname/public_html/config_db.php on line 3
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

**Additional Info** - I have a shared webhosting account and as far as I can tell there no triggers (dB update etc) that seem to cause this.  When I check the error_log, once in a while I see these connection errors

Comment: hmmm.. would you add some detail? like is this on a local host, a shared webhosting, aws? Do the error seem to happen during an update of your code?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have a shared hosting account and i can't tie these errors to anything that I'm doing eg. DB update etc. Really perplexing. Please let know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: Are there multiple places where you connect to your database? What I mean is do you use the same pdo connection throughout a single script call?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I do include the same script in files where I need DB access. And I also make sure that I close the DB connection as soon as I'm done via $dbConn = NULL; I know that on shared hosting there is a 15 concurrent DB connection limit but I don't think I'm hitting that!

Comment: If you are including the file in multiple files, that could mean that multiple connections are actually created for a single script run, even if you close then afterwards. You would normally pass the database object as a parameter to the functions needing it. To verify this, you could log the result of `SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Threads_connected';`

Comment: That's a good point. I will add this to my debug and see if this is indeed whats happening. I will report back on this thread once I get some data. I really appreciate your time and advice. Thanks!!